Will the following Method of engineering analysis work?
Analytical Engineering Analysis of 3D Shapes
Using volume integral($\iiint_{}^{}{f(t)}dx dy dz$) to do a Analytical
Engineering Analysis of 3D Shapes without using mesh based FEA. Like
integration calculates area under curve and FEA do a filled rectangular
mesh or cubic mesh approximation of shapes for engineering analysis here
propose modified volume integral method to Analytical Engineering
Analysis of 3D Shapes. Volume integral is where ∆x, ∆y, ∆z tends to
zero. The difference between regular volume integral is that the
function should change after each integration of volume integration ( 3
steps of integration). For example,.
Required continuous smooth function of stress or heat in a 3D solid
shape
$$= \int_{}^{}{h(G(t))\int_{}^{}{g(F(t))\int_{}^{}{f(t)dx\ dy\ dz}}}$$
Where, $$F(t) = \int_{}^{}{f(t)}$$
, $$G(t) =\int_{}^{}{g(t)}$$
If $f(t) = sin(t)$ , $g(t) = 2x$ , $h(t) = x^{2}$
then ,
$$\int_{}^{}{{(G(t))}^{2}\int_{}^{}{2F(t)\int_{}^{}{\sin{t\ dx\ dy\ dz}}}}$$
The boundary conditions are given as limits $(u(x), u(y), u(z) .. v(x),
v(y), v(z) )$ of integration
$$\int_{v(x)}^{u(x)}{h(G(t))\int_{v(y)}^{u(y)}{g(F(t))\int_{v(z)}^{u(z)}{f(t)dx\ dy\ dz}}}$$
This is a new engineering analysis where a continuous plot of result is
made; unlike FEA, where discrete results are made that depends on size
or number of elements. this will revolutionize engineering analysis
where the results of engineering analysis are like a vector image rather
than raster image.
In this, Upper and Lower limit can be a range; for example, 1:100 with
0.1 as step size. So we get 1000 X 1000 X 1000= 1 billion total cells.
Shapes can be converted to polynomials using key coordinates from CAD
data and using matrix method of finding coefficients using linear
algebra; similar to solving a set of equations. Polynomials are easy to
integrate.
will the above method work?

Is anybody interested in collaboratively develop the above concept further
